# How to access audio features from Spotify Player JS library

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm trying to use this [spotify player js library](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-player) to access the audio features of a currently playing song. I don't know how I should use the [endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#endpoint-get-audio-features) in my code to get the audio features (such as valence and energy) to print in my console. Right now, it just displays the name of the song and the artist when I play the song on my laptop. Here is the code that I have based on this one codepen that the person who made the library made for demo.

```
var mainContainer = document.getElementById('js-main-container'),
    loginContainer = document.getElementById('js-login-container'),
    loginButton = document.getElementById('js-btn-login'),

var spotifyPlayer = new SpotifyPlayer();

var template = function (data) {
  return `
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <div class="now-playing__side">
        <div class="now-playing__name">${data.item.name}</div>
        <div class="now-playing__artist">${data.item.artists[0].name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
};

var artistsCache = {},
    artistFetching = false;
spotifyPlayer.on('update', response => {
  var mainArtist = response.item.artists[0];
  if (!(mainArtist.id in artistsCache) && !artistFetching) {
    artistFetching = true;
    spotifyPlayer.fetchGeneric(mainArtist.href)
      .then(function(artist) {
        artistFetching = false;
        return artist.json();
      }).then(function(artist) {
        if (artist.images.length) {
          artistsCache[artist.id] = artist.images[0].url;
        }
      }).catch(function(e) {
        artistFetching = false;
      });
  }
  mainContainer.innerHTML = template(response);
});

spotifyPlayer.on('login', user => {
  if (user === null) {
    loginContainer.style.display = 'block';
    mainContainer.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    loginContainer.style.display = 'none';
    mainContainer.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

loginButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    spotifyPlayer.login();
});

spotifyPlayer.init();
```